# Getting the Difference of Time in a List of Dates

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Trying to calculate the difference between two lists of dates and output the difference.

The dates were treated as an object that are a string I changed that but now I only get the dates.

```bsh
$TrimmedImport1 = $import1 -replace '"', "" |
                  Set-Content -Path "$env:TEMP\Time Finished.csv"
$TrimmedImport  = $import -replace '"', "" |
                  Set-Content -Path "$env:TEMP\Time Created.csv"

$ContentSetter1 = Get-Content -Path "$env:TEMP\Time Finished.csv"
$ContentSetter  = Get-Content -Path "$env:TEMP\Time Finished.csv"

foreach ($TimeConverted1 in $ContentSetter1) {
    [DateTime]$TimeConverted1
}
"`n"
foreach ($TimeConverted in $ContentSetter) {
    [DateTime]$TimeConverted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Import-Csv` for reading the original files (there's no need to manually "trim" the data). For calculating the difference between corresponding data rows use a `For` loop, so you can iterate over both arrays at the same time.

The code sample below is based on the assumption that your input files consist of a single column with no header. If that assumption is incorrect you need to adjust the code accordingly.

```bsh
$created  = Import-Csv "$env:TEMP\Time Created.csv" -Header 'Timestamp' |
            Select-Object -Expand Timestamp
$finished = Import-Csv "$env:TEMP\Time Finished.csv" -Header 'Timestamp' |
            Select-Object -Expand Timestamp

for ($i=0; $i -lt $created.Count; $i++) {
    ([DateTime]$created[$i]) - ([DateTime]$finished[$i])
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to export that data difference to another csv ?

Comment: @abdullahalhamidi Of course there is. Just select what you want exported and write that to a file. Since you had to ask you may want to pick up a PowerShell tutorial first, though.